# read from .csv and simulate keyboard input (C++ and Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, csv, simulate

Under windows and in C++ how to read from .csv lines by order and simulate keyboard input in a certain program window depending on values in .csv file for example:
in xyz.csv file:

a

b

a=alt+f , b=ctrl+alt+del

so "alt+f" is simulated first then "ctrl+alt+del" in window def.exe

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: how to simulate keyboard input that is read respectively from csv file